# fsck error on boot: /dev/sda1: UNEXPECTED INCONSISTENCY; RUN fsck MANUALLY

Tags: boot, kali-linux, fsck

I have Kali linux 2020.3 installed in a Virtual Box VM. Today when I started the VM, I got an error like this

[image: fsck failure]

This is the same error as https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060549/unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually-multiple-times and https://askubuntu.com/questions/697190/fsck-error-on-boot-dev-sda6-unexpected-inconsistency-run-fsck-manually. I tried all the solutions specified  but none of them worked.

When I use  `fsck -fy /dev/sda1`, it again get stuck at [here][2]:

[image: fsck failure]

Any idea why this happened?

Answer (score 3):

`Buffer I/O error on dev sda1` would indicate problems with communicating with the disk. On a physical system these might suggest a failing disk or a bad SATA cable, or a similar hardware failure. But you said this is a VirtualBox VM.

Where is your Kali VM's virtual disk stored? If it is on e.g. on an external USB disk, check that the connection is good and the disk is not failing.

The SCSI-style error messages include `Illegal Request... Unaligned write command` and `Illegal Request... Logical block address out of range`. The former would be very unusual unless the disk uses 4kiB block size and this is now not being handled properly. The latter suggests something is trying to access beyond the end of the disk, which could also happen when the logical block size presented by the disk has changed for some reason.

Have you changed anything in your hardware set-up, in particularly anything related to the physical disk that contains the Kali VM's virtual disk, between the last time the VM worked correctly and the time you noticed the failure the first time?

For example, have you taken a disk out of an external USB enclosure (which might use 4kiB blocks natively) and plugged it into the system's regular internal SATA controller (which usually uses classic 512-byte blocks) or vice versa?

Comment: I haven't done any changes to the VM, I just shutted down the VM as usual. After like 2 hours when I started it again I got this error. The VDI file used in the VM is not in an external USB, it's located in my C: drive (which is not where my Windows installation is)

Comment: Perhaps your C: drive is failing? You might want to check its SMART diagnostics. I hear CrystalDiskInfo is a pretty good free Windows tool for that.

Comment: I think you are right. I tried to copy the VDI file to a different location and attach it to the VM again. And Windows fails to copy it. It gives me an error saying "Can't read from the source file or disk". But I noticed this error before in one of my other VMs which are working fine even with this issue. So I doubt that this is causing the issue with my Kali VM

Comment: If Windows cannot read the VDI file, it means the file has a broken spot somewhere in it. If your other VM happens to have the broken spot correspond to some unimportant file within the VM, you might not even notice. But on the Kali VM, the broken spot seems to be where important filesystem metadata needs to be. And if your disk already has broken spots, they might get worse over time.

Comment: Actually, I use that VM(other VM) almost every day. Also the that VM still works fine, so I don't think this is a problem with the drive itself but with the VDI file. If so is there anyway I can fix this, or even recover my data?

Comment: It was already explained why it is very likely the problem. You should check the Windows drive indeed.

Comment: @KavishkaGihan You have a bad disk. The fault affects one of your VMs (regardless of the fact that other VMs are not affected, yet). Consider replacing the physical disk.

Comment: Even though I have to change the physical disk, can't I sill recover the data that I have in the VDI file?

Comment: The data in the VDI file is stored on the physical disk, and if the physical disk has a bad spot, it will affect anything and everything that would use that spot. First, use `ddrescue` or similar to image the entire failing C: drive to the new disk; after that, you can work with the good disk, attach the Kali VDI as a second virtual disk to another, working VM, and use PhotoREC or similar recovery software within the VM to recover files from it. But check the contents of any important files: if a file was sitting on top of a bad spot, some of its data might have been lost or corrupted.

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same issue this morning and I fixed it by running the command below

fsck /dev/sda1

Then and I accepted to fix all the issues.